# What happens when I try to copy an object with `thecopy := object` instead of object.Clone()?

Tags: autohotkey

```
thearray := [6,77,4,3,66,11]
thecopy := thearray
MsgBox % thecopy.Length() ; 6 
thearray := function(thearray)
MsgBox % thecopy.Length() ; 0
MsgBox % thearray.Length() ; 6
```

Why is thecopy "ruined" when thearray is changed by a function? My guess: The function changes the thearray. Therefor thecopy, which I guess is some kind of reference (?) to the same array as 'thearray' was, is invalid or something. Is this the right way to think about this? I'm all new to this reference thing or whatever it is.

And by the way, if `.Clone()` is added in the end of the second row thecopy remains intact.

Comment: Assigning doesn't copy anything, it's just a reference, a pointer.

Comment: Ok, but why is `notacopy := var` just assigning var's value, and is unchanged if var is changed? Isn't this, at least in practise, a copy?

Comment: I don't see the value of `var` so I guess that was a *literal* value, not an object/array.